# Erro com session em PHP

Tags: php, session

Estou fazendo uma pagina de cadastro utilizando PHP. Tenho uma validação para mostrar ao usuário se o cadastro já foi efetuado ou não, mas está sempre retornando  sempre `Notice: Undefined index: status_cadastro in C:\xampp\htdocs\login-php-usb\cadastro.php on line 25`.

HTML:

```
            <?php
            if($_SESSION['status_cadastro']):
            ?>
              <div class="notification is-success">
                 <p>Cadastro efetuado!</p>
                 <p>Faça login informando o seu usuário e senha <a href="login.php">aqui</a></p>
               </div>
            <?php
            endif;
            unset($_SESSION['status_cadastro']);
            ?>
```

Arquivo **cadastrar.php** com as sessions:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("conexao.php");

$nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, trim($_POST['nome']));
$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, trim($_POST['usuario']));
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, trim(md5($_POST['senha'])));

$sql = "select count(*) as total from usuario_web where usuario = '$usuario'";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if($row['total'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['usuario_existe'] = true;
    header('Location: cadastro.php');
    exit;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO usuario_web (nome, usuario, senha, data_cadastro) VALUES ('$nome', '$usuario', '$senha', NOW())";

if($conexao->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $_SESSION['status_cadastro'] = true;
}

$conexao->close();

header('Location: cadastro.php');
exit;
?>
```

Creio que o erro seja com a session, mas não consegui indentificar, alguém teria ideia?

Comment: Você chegou a iniciar a session nesse seu arquivo que contém o html ?

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson sim: `<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 `

Comment: A linha 25 que está sendo mencionada na mensagem de erro é aquela do unset ou a do IF ?

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson seria do if. https://ibb.co/m8L5ffH

Comment: @AlgeuJunior, sabe o que está acontecendo. acredito que você está tentando acessar um atributo da Session antes dela ser criada. Tipo. Você está renderizando o HTML, antes de ter iniciado a session .com este atributo.
tipo $_SESSION['status_cadastro'] = false;
if($conexao->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $_SESSION['status_cadastro'] = true;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está tentando acessar um atributo da session que só $_SESSION['status_cadastro'] só será criada se entrar em um if($conexao->query($sql) === TRUE):

Arquivo **cadastrar.php** com as sessions:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("conexao.php");

$nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, trim($_POST['nome']));
$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, trim($_POST['usuario']));
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, trim(md5($_POST['senha'])));

$sql = "select count(*) as total from usuario_web where usuario = '$usuario'";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if($row['total'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['usuario_existe'] = true;
    header('Location: cadastro.php');
    exit;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO usuario_web (nome, usuario, senha, data_cadastro) VALUES ('$nome', '$usuario', '$senha', NOW())";
//Seta $_SESSION['status_cadastro'] antes da validação 
$_SESSION['status_cadastro'] = false;

if($conexao->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $_SESSION['status_cadastro'] = true;
}

$conexao->close();

header('Location: cadastro.php');
exit;
?>
```

Espero ter ajudado;